# como ejecutar una funcion ajax desde html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Buenos días resulta que tengo un botón en un archivo html y tengo una funcion ajax en el mismo archivo y todo perfecto   pero lo que quiero es que la funcion ajax de javascript este otro archivo en otra carpeta como puedo hacerlo sin afectar la funcion del click del boton?

este es mi ajax lo que quiero es separarlo del html en otro archivo pero como lo enlazo

```
<script>
$("#ini").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email1").val();
    var pass = $("#password1").val();
    $.ajax({
        url :   "login.php",
        method: "POST",
        data    :   {Email:email,Password:pass},
        success :function(data){

            if(data == "ok"){
            //  window.location.href = "profile.php";
             $("#mostrarmodal1").modal("hide");
            location.href="usernav";
            } else {
                     alert("Usuario o contrasena invalida");
            }

        }
    })
})

  </script>
```

Comment: Hola, creo que ya tienes experiencia en el sitio para saber que una pregunta de este tipo sin código y con una explicación tan parca en detalles no se considera de buena calidad. Por favor, incluye el código HTML/JS que estás usando e indica qué problemas tienes

Comment: entiendo ya puse el codigo ajax el html no importa lo que quiero es separar la funcion en otro archivo llamado inicio.js

Comment: Hola, recuerda que la redacción es muy importante. En tu pregunta, aparte de los acentos, el único signo de puntuación es el de interrogación (en toda la pregunta). Usa la coma, punto y coma, punto seguido y punto aparte de forma adecuada, así tu pregunta tendrá mayor sentido. Te invito a hacer clic en [edit] para que corrijas la redacción. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas guardar todo tu codigo en un archivo .js

> ajax.js

```
$("#ini").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email1").val();
    var pass = $("#password1").val();
    $.ajax({
        url :   "login.php",
        method: "POST",
        data    :   {Email:email,Password:pass},
        success :function(data){

            if(data == "ok"){
            //  window.location.href = "profile.php";
             $("#mostrarmodal1").modal("hide");
            location.href="usernav";
            } else {
                     alert("Usuario o contrasena invalida");
            }

        }
    })
})
```

Luego lo importas de esta manera en tu archivo html

> archivo.html

```
<script src="./ajax.js"></script>
```

Dependiendo de la carpeta donde desees poner el archivo ajax.js cambia la ruta.

Comment: ya lo hice cuando paso el codigo javascript al nuevo archivo me marca este error :  expetecd an identifier an instead saw

Comment: el error me sale en el archivo js y al final de el error me sale unclosed regular expression

Comment: Entonces es por un error de sintaxis. Puedes subir capturas de tus archivos HTML y JS para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: lo estraño es que todo en un mismo archivo html funciona perfecto

Comment: Como lo explica @Pablo Lozano, trata de agregar la informacion necesaria para que la pregunta se entienda mejor y se resuelva mas rapido

Comment: gracias ya lo solucione al parecer el error era al principio escribí <script> y no era necesario